# Service method called twice

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework, rest, wcf-data-services

I have created a rest service using wcf.
I am writing Entity framework code within a service method to fetch data from database.

Every call from browser is hitting the service method twice or thrice.
I found no exception within the method. I encountered same problem before and solved it adding DataContract attribute to all the models(not helping now).

What may be the possible reasons? Please help.

Regards
Ashish

Comment: [Have you tried using WCF diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 4):

Tracing the web service is the point to start from.

1.- Add the following to the web.config in your WCF project:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true">
</trace>
<sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
            <add name="sdt"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="WcfDetailTrace.e2e" />
        </listeners>
    </source>
</sources>
```

Then execute your service and checkout the contents of the file "WcfDetaiTrace.e2e" inside the project folder, it's an XML file. That way you will find easily what's wrong with your service. The main problems are related to:

1. Missing DataContracts/KnownTypes
2. DateTime serialization exception (overflow)
3. Using wrong verb to access REST entry (GET but should be POST, PUT or DELETE)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great. It really helps, otherwise you have no idea, WTH is causing trouble.

Comment: What would interest me: Why is the method called a second time when there are problems with serialization? I don't see the benefit in executing the code twice. Also: Is it possible to disable that behaviour so that instead of executing the method twice, an error is thrown as soon as the serialization fails?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it has error to serialize data contract that is why it called the same method twice. Please check your data contract class for duplicate properties or any other issue.